# Comment.tpl.php how to add a link back to the node

Tags: theming, comments

In the comment.tpl.php I've shown the comment parent node title by:

```
$node->title
```

I need to make this title link back to the parent node:

$node->$node_url

But this doesn't work. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [entity_uri()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_uri/7) and [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) functions, similar to how it's done in [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7):

```
$uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
$link = l($node->title, $uri['path'], $uri['options']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should almost work now, I think you missed a print right before the `url()`.

However, it's unsafe to simply print the node title without properly escaping it with `check_plain()`. So that's another good reason to use the `l()` function.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. please don't add promotion links to your answers. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your goal with the following line of code:

`<a href="<?php print url('node/'.$node->nid) ?>"><?php print $node->title; ?></a>`.

Comment: That call to the url() function is not going to work. Also, it's preferred to use the l() function to generate `<a>` tags.

Comment: Your code should almost work now, I think you missed a `print` right before the `url()`. However, it's unsafe to simply print the node title without properly escaping it with [check_plain()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7). So that's another good reason to use the l() function.

Comment: I'm sure it works at first sight. But guess what happens if you create a node with the title `<script>alert('Hi');</script>`, and think what that means for the security of your site and the people visiting it. I'm not saying you *must* use `l()`, but using it would automatically have prevented a security mistake like this one.